# Distance-preserving graph contraction to a given set of vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to resolve the following problem and was wondering if there already exists consecrated algorithms to solve it.

Let $G(V,E)$ be a weighted graph 
with vertices $V$ connected through weighted edges $E$.
Given a subset $S \subset V$,
perform graph contraction such that all edges are removed until only the vertices in $S$ remain and the distance-preserving edges connecting them.
If there exists more than one edges connecting two nodes from $S$,
pick the smallest weight and remove the other(s).

The "Distance-preserving graph contractions" [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.04544.pdf) from Bernstein et al. was the closest I could find to my problem, but their goal is different (for one, they are not bound by a set $S$).

The min-cut class of problems seems also close-by, but not exactly what I want.

Can you please point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: Just some clarification: By contract a vertex $v$ [of degree greater than 2], you mean remove $v$ from $G$ and then, for every two neighbours $u_1$ and $u_2$ of $v$, put the edge $u_1u_2$ and set the length $\ell(u_1u_2)$ of the edge $u_1u_2$ to $\ell(u_1u_2) = \ell(u_1v) + \ell(vu_2)$ [and then do something to take care of duplicate edges]?

Comment: Of course you can always do something like that above--contract vertices not in $S$ and the pairwise distances between vertices in $S$ will be preserved. The main issue is that the resulting graph may in fact be different topologically, in that e.g., the original graph had a small cut that bisected $S$ but the new resulting graph does not.

Comment: @Mike's first comment: yes, that is what I want to do. The extra merge step removes all but the smallest edge connecting any given two vertices that used to be connected through $v$.